# Alternative way to power a mains 12 watt LED

Tags: led, ac, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, mains

So I'm pretty excited, I'm about to finish my project but now my problem is I bought a bulb led today and I do not have anymore resources to provide a 60hz 230v to it, since that is its specification.

Wanted to know if my available method can still power it, which is a 10khz to 20khz 230 volt AC supply... An alternative would be a DC voltage at the 200 volts...

So I'm curious if the the led bulb (image attached) would still work at a high frequency input or a DC input as long as it is the required 220v - 240v?

Reason why I ask is because I'm assuming it's using a SMPS thus it would rectify whatever ac voltage I provide before converting it to high frequency ac to be stepped down to the desired LED voltage.... Please feel free to elaborate and discuss. Thank you

[image]

Comment: If it's a SMPS, it's bridge rectifier is unlikely to be made out of fast enough diodes, so no. If it's a capacitive dropper then the frequency is way too high for that to work correctly, so also no.

Comment: It looks transparent enough that you can figure out what power supply it uses. But why didn't you get LEDs that work with the power supply you have?

Comment: So you telling me I have no choice but a 230V AC at 60hz

Comment: And can't I mess around with the circuit? So I can just feed it 12v DC?

Comment: You can certainly mess around with the circuit but first you'll need to see what kind of circuit it is.

Comment: I can see a ring of LEDs in there. They're probably connected in series. You would have to cut traces and attach wires and current limiting into paralleled strings of three series LEDs.

Comment: You could pre-rectify your high-frequency 230Vac using diodes or a bridge which is fast enough to handle your 10-20kHz, and then feed the rectified DC to the LED module (assuming the module has an internal SMPS).

Comment: Ain't no switching power supply in that bulb.  In the middle is a big capacitor, and to the left and right of it are thick, black through hole diodes.  Probably relatives of the 1N4001 but rated for a higher voltage.  Nothing there but a rectifier, a filter capacitor, and somewhere hidden inside a smaller capacitor for current limiting.

Comment: Cheap lights like this are almost always a large number of diode junctions in series to get the series forward voltage close to the line voltage followed by a linear regulator. You could probably feed it DC at the right voltage, but lower voltage won't work.

Comment: Crack it open and trace out the schematic. From there you can determine what you can and can’t do.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the transparent looks, it is a rectifier, electrolytic storage cap and series cap before the rectifier (see JREs comment)

This series capacitor will make the LEDs rather dim when using lower voltage, so you need to change or parallel them with a larger one.

Comment: Probably not a series resistor.  More likely a capacitor.

Comment: well there has to be some series resistors. There are only 15 LEDs which can use maximum ~50 V. Powering them off 325 VDC mandates series resistors.

Comment: Nope. Powering them off 325V mandates a series capacitor before the rectifier.  Look up "capacitive dropper."  A resistor would have to convert about 60 to 70 watts to heat. A 12 watt LED at 50V would be about 0.24A.  In dropping from 325V to 50 V, that would be about 275V*0.24A = 66W.  That'd be a heck of a resistor.

Comment: Makes sense. Never thought about that obviously :-) I